# SharePoint 2010 error on ECMA get_item

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to retrieve the 'Description' field of a list. This is a default field created by SharePoint that I cannot delete or make it not-required.
The connection works fine.

My Code:

```
 function getCoursesToDelete() 
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CoursesToDelete'); 
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
 camlQuery.set_viewXml('<GetListItems><Query /><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Description" />  </ViewFields><QueryOptions /></GetListItems>');
 this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
 clientContext.load(collListItem);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

and then:

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender,args)
{
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

 while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) 
 {
   var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current(); 
   alert(oListItem.get_item('Description'));
 }
}
```

Comment: did you miss this line in the real code ? var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

Comment: oh no, I just forgot to copy it here. thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to set Required property for field via CSOM

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle); 
var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);

field.set_required(false);
field.update();

context.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {    
         console.log('Field has been set as optional');
      },
      function (sender, args) {
         console.log(args.get_message());
      }
);
```

### How to delete field from List via CSOM

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle); 
var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);

field.deleteObject();
context.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {    
         console.log('Field has been deleted from a List');
      },
      function (sender, args) {
         console.log(args.get_message());
      }
);
```